# speed of handling input: growing an array, or counting input, allocating, and then reading

Tags: c++, input, runtime, big-o

Basically I am wondering what would be a faster way of handling input from standard input:

Method one: Declaring an array of some arbitrary size, reading into the array, and if the input is more than the size, allocate a new array twice the size, copying the contents into the new array, and deallocating the previous array.

Method two: Read the whole input and count the number of lines while reading.  reset the pointer back to the top of the input, declare an array of the length of the size of the number of lines, and then input into that array.
some background:

1. I'm not using vectors.  please don't say to just use vectors...
2. they won't be typing the input, it'll be redirected from the command line to a file.  akin to `./program < input.txt`
3. I understand that the first method is more inefficient in terms of space, but is it faster than method two?  if so, by how much?  method 2 essentially takes 2n time to finish.  I want to know if the first method would increase the runtime of my code.

Comment: io is likely sloooow slow.  do first with possibly http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/realloc/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both methods are O(n). However, you're reading from `stdin`, so there's no way to rewind it back to the beginning unless something is *already* storing the data somewhere, so I don't see how you could use method 2.

You would need to use method 1. If you can use `realloc`, it might not even have to do any copying. If you're worried about the extra copying, you can store the items in a linked-list of buffers of exponentially increasing size, then create a single array at the end and copy each one only once.

Comment: Damn... no +2 possible in SO :-)